# Why component App is rerendering in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Every time you click on the button, the App component is re-rendered. Why does this happen if the set function is wrapped in useCallback in the useMyCallback component? And in theory, set should always have the same value.

App.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import useMyCallback from "../../hooks/useMyCallback";

const App = () => {
  const hook = useMyCallback();

  console.log("render");

  return <button onClick={hook}>Click</button>;
};
```

useMyCallback.jsx

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const useMyCallback = () => {
  const [_, setState] = useState([1]);

  const set = useCallback((e) => {
    return setState((pr) => [...pr, pr + 1]);
  }, []);

  return set;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not exporting your custom hook.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const UseMyCallback = () => {
  ...
};

export default UseMyCallback;
```

You import it like this with a lower case **u**

```js
import useMyCallback from "../../hooks/useMyCallback";
```

but you use like this

```js
const hook = UseMyCallback();
```

which should be

```js
const hook = useMyCallback();
```

With that out of the way, you're updating the state which triggers a re-render. It does not matter that you're only returning the setter, even in a useCallback. You're still changing the state.

Comment: You're right, I had a typo. But you didn't answer the main question. Why is the app being re-rendered?